# List Under ListView Item

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, datagrid, listbox

I have listview that binding with observable Collection, this listview show the invoice items, any item  in invoice maybe has a sub detail (Options), (for example item color),
what i want to ask about is: how to make list view show the item options as list under the main item in listview, i hope my question is clear .. for more clarity look at the image :

[image]

What i want is in a yellow color, how to make listview look like the image ?

here's my invoice listview code :

```
            <ListView x:Name="temsReceipt" ItemsSource="{Binding ocItemsReceipt}">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView ColumnHeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource myHeaderStyle}">
                    <GridViewColumn>
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Height="40" Width="50"></TextBlock>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Item Name" Width="230" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ItemName}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Item Price" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ItemPrice}"/>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
```

The same think if i used the datagrid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say that you have following classes:

```
class InvoiceItem
{
    public string ItemName { get; set; }
    public List<InvoiceOption> Options { get; set; }
}

class InvoiceOption
{
    public string OptionName { get; set; }
}
```

ListView solution:

```
<ListView x:Name="temsReceipt" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <ListView.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        </Style>
    </ListView.Resources>
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Height="40" Width="50"></TextBlock>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Item Name" Width="230" >
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="40" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>                                   
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ItemName}" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                                       FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="18"/>
                            <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Options}" Grid.Row="1" Background="Yellow" 
                                     HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding OptionName}" />
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            </ListBox>
                        </Grid>                                
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Item Price" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ItemPrice}"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

If you want to use DataGrid you can use RowDetailsTemplate:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding ItemName}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Margin="2" Background="Yellow">
                <TextBlock Text="Options:" />
                <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Options}">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding OptionName}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
</DataGrid>
```

Sample data:

```
...
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    List<InvoiceItem> _source = new List<InvoiceItem>
    {
        new InvoiceItem
        {
          ItemName = "Item1",
          Options = new List<InvoiceOption>
          {
              new InvoiceOption { OptionName = "Option1" },
              new InvoiceOption { OptionName = "Option2" }
          }
        },
        new InvoiceItem
        {
          ItemName = "Item2",
          Options = new List<InvoiceOption>
          {
              new InvoiceOption { OptionName = "Option3" },
              new InvoiceOption { OptionName = "Option4" }
          }
        }
    };

    this.DataContext = _source;
}
...
```

ListView result:

[image]

Comment: I'd suggest to remove the first column which looks like its fuction is to provide margin and use a padding instead.

Comment: kmatyaszek, i have tray this with both listView and datagrid but didn't work, the options list appear empty, any suggest ?

Comment: @AbdusalamElsherif check my answer again, I added sample data and result image. Could you show me your model classes ?

Comment: oky kmatyaszek, i miss 'ElementName' for my options 'Binding' it's work now, Thanks so much